# How to add an Oracle Server for a Visual Studio 2012 MVC Entity Framework Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I have been trying to add an Oracle Server via Add Connection option provided in the Data Connections Section of Server Explorer.
I have been using Oracle 10g Express Edition to connect to via Entity Framework.
Whenever I pot for adding the server connection is throws up errors. What am I possibly missing ? I tried all the solutions I could find on net and here is what my connectionString looks like :

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=
         (ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST= CHIRANJIB_VAIO)(PORT=1521)))
         (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME= XE)));
        User Id=hr ;Password=hr" />
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication4-20151115215423;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication4-20151115215423.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Below are the screenshots of my attempts at it :

[image]

and ....

[image]

I tried 'XE' , 'localhost' etc. as the Server Names . But apparently nothing worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `HOST = CHIRANJIB_VAIO` to `HOST = localhost` if it's a local server, and check in your `tnsnames.ora` file to be sure that it's a `DEDICATED` server.

Also, have you installed the `NuGet package`?

Comment: Yes I have Changed. But that did not also work out. I have installed the NuGet package.

Comment: Have you opened your TNS Names file?

Comment: I could not find it. It says $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin does not exist. :(

Comment: Then you probably don't have a running Oracle listener. Run the database configuration tool. Can you connect from SQL Developer?

Comment: I do not have SQL Developer . But I have already started the Oracle Database.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with 10g clients, you can use the EZCONNECT feature, which does not require to edit the TNSNAMES.ORA file. For instance:

```
<add name="RagTools" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/DEV;PASSWORD=***;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=UserName" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
```